# Native Wifi Api C++.Off/on wifi

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want write program for on/off wifi modules on C++ NativeWifi.
I received All modules.Then I do not know what to do.I have no experience in NativeWifi Api.Please help me, thank.

```
HANDLE hClient = NULL;
DWORD dwMaxClient = 2;      //    
DWORD dwCurVersion = 0;
DWORD dwResult = 0;
DWORD dwRetVal = 0;
int iRet = 0;

WCHAR GuidString[39] = { 0 };

unsigned int i, j, k;

/* variables used for WlanEnumInterfaces  */

PWLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST pIfList = NULL;
PWLAN_INTERFACE_INFO pIfInfo = NULL;

PWLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_LIST pBssList = NULL;
PWLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK pBssEntry = NULL;

dwResult = WlanOpenHandle(dwMaxClient, NULL, &dwCurVersion, &hClient);
if (dwResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    wprintf(L"WlanOpenHandle failed with error: %u\n", dwResult);
    return 1;
    // You can use FormatMessage here to find out why the function failed
}

dwResult = WlanEnumInterfaces(hClient, NULL, &pIfList);
if (dwResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    wprintf(L"WlanEnumInterfaces failed with error: %u\n", dwResult);
    return 1;
    // You can use FormatMessage here to find out why the function failed
}
else {
    wprintf(L"Num Entries: %lu\n", pIfList->dwNumberOfItems);
    wprintf(L"Current Index: %lu\n", pIfList->dwIndex);
    for (i = 0; i < (int)pIfList->dwNumberOfItems; i++) {
        pIfInfo = (WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO *)&pIfList->InterfaceInfo[i];
        wprintf(L"  Interface Index[%u]:\t %lu\n", i, i);
        iRet = StringFromGUID2(pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid, (LPOLESTR)&GuidString,
            sizeof(GuidString) / sizeof(*GuidString));
        // For c rather than C++ source code, the above line needs to be
        // iRet = StringFromGUID2(&pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid, (LPOLESTR) &GuidString, 
        //     sizeof(GuidString)/sizeof(*GuidString)); 
        if (iRet == 0)
            wprintf(L"StringFromGUID2 failed\n");
        else {
            wprintf(L"  InterfaceGUID[%d]: %ws\n", i, GuidString);
        }


    }

}
```

I received All modules.Next, The radio state of a PHY is off if either dot11SoftwareRadioState or dot11HardwareRadioState member of the WLAN_PHY_RADIO_STATE structure is dot11_radio_state_off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation of [`WLAN_PHY_RADIO_STATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706918(v=vs.85).aspx) states, you can use `WlanSetInterface` to turn the **software** radio state off.

Comment: @Yura: ?? You can't change the enum, it's defined by Windows. It's shorthand for " unknown=0, on =1, off = 2 "